# Unique word count

Tags: programming-languages, word-count

This is a generic question that applies to (probably) any high-level programming language.
Here is the situation:

Suppose I have an array of strings. Say, I managed to put 500 000 strings from a short story into an array (just suppose you don't have an option for input format). Consequently, there will most likely be an arbitrary number of duplicated items.

I want to take this array of strings and create another array that contains a unique subset(?) of that array (ie: no duplicates). In this scenario, both the input and output must be arrays, so that may restrict you from various options.

Performance-wise, what's the fastest way to accomplish this? I'm currently using a linear search to check whether a word exists already, but as it is a linear search I feel that there might be faster ways especially if I have unreasonable amounts of strings to work with. Like a bigger novel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a hashset might be the most sensible thing to do - complexity should be O(N).

Note: most high-level programming languages contain an implementation of a function that removes duplicates from an array, e.g. [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: Or a hash based set, a map implies you have a key and a value, but you could use the value to store a count.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant an hashset. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be putting gazillions of words into it, a [directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) is the most efficient data structure I know of.

And yet it is conceptually a very simple data structure.

Comment: A *minimal* directed acyclic word graph is very very slow to generate, so that’s not really an option. Maybe you just mean a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which is the “least minimalised” word graph; this is much faster to generate, but depending on the dictionary can be memory-hungry. I would still recommend a hashset for what the OP is trying to do. (Although if the OP is going to do a lot of word fiddling, finding out about DAWGs and tries may be interesting in its own right.)

Comment: @Timwi perhaps I _do_ mean a trie - I always thought "DAWG" referred to this family of concepts rather than a specific one.

Comment: Technically, I suppose DAWG is the more general term and a trie *is* a special case of a DAWG. But in practice, the term DAWG seems to usually refer to a *minimal* DAWG...